# full-screen div is shifted down when contains h1 element only

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I have trouble to create a page with full screen div with h1 element.

Following page is rendered correctly by IE and Chrome as expected: Contains Red full-screen div, no scroll-bars:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
        html {
            background-color: purple;
        }
        body {
            background-color: blue;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #main {
            background-color: red;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>
            some text
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But, for the Firefox (27.0.1) I found:

- show purple line at the top of the page
- and vertical scroll-bar
- if I add some text directly to #main div before h1 element, then page renders as expected.

What I should do to render it correctly in FireFox with text in h1 only ?

Answer (score 2):

> Following page is rendered correctly by IE and Chrome as expected: Contains Red full-screen div

If that’s what you get, then that can only be in Quirks Mode, I suppose – because you forgot to set `height:100%` for `html` as well, and without that the percentage height for `body` is not *supposed* to work that way.

And with a correct Doctype set (and height for html), you get the same result in all standards conform browser – the one you *think* is wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/q6g8Q/1/

It’s actually correct though, because of [adjoining margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) – the default `margin-top` from the browser stylesheet for the `h1` adjoins the margin-top of the `div` – and therefor it gets pushed down accordingly.

So set the `margin-top` of the `h1` to zero, and the “problem” is gone – http://jsfiddle.net/q6g8Q/2/

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the css of your browser. Just add this to the top of your css :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

// #main h1 { margin:0; } // this snippet will be enough for your case, but with the other you remove every margin and padding made by the browser.
```

[demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aM2d2/)

If you want more info about this tricks,  read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/) by Chris Coyier.

If you want a full css reset, you should consider the [Reset Reloaded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/).

Comment: @jozef You should read the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234348/full-screen-div-is-shifted-down-when-contains-h1-element-only/22234462?noredirect=1#comment33764309_22234462) of CBroe . I did not take the time to answer about the second part of the question; he did. By the way, he give more information than I.

Answer (score 0):

change the line-height or margin padding. That should do the trick. play around with some big numbers ;)