# How to tell where a horizontally centered element is exactly, if it is not precise in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, alignment, centering

A picture and a fiddle is worth more than a thousand words:

http://jsfiddle.net/xrer55r7/

[image]

Slowly resize the window and see the striped background mis-aligned every now and then. I'm logging the position in the console, which doesn't change at all. Visually it does, though.

Chrome aligns a horizontally centered element (with `text-align: center;`) in another horizontally centered element (with `margin: 0 auto;`) in a way that it rounds the apparent position, resulting in a visual change. It is not reflected in the position I get for the element using jQuery's  `.position()`.

Bascically the problem is not present in Firefox/Safari, is there to some extent on IE (in my application it doesn't cause a problem), but it is very prominent on Chrome.

I need a way to get or calculate this position OR to disable this behavior OR a workaround for the background to not misalign while keeping everything centered.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="centered good">
        This is just fine! :)
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="centered bad">
        This is not :(
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    .box {
        width: 313px;
        height: 206px;
        background: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAgABAIAAACmd/////ywAAAAAAgABAAACAkQKADs=');
        position:relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .centered{
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        padding: 5px;
        background: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAgABAIAAACmd/////ywAAAAAAgABAAACAkQKADs=');
        font-size:15px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: If you change the font size to an even number it seems to fix it [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrer55r7/2/)

Comment: I changed the width to `314px` it should be `313px`

Comment: In your modified fiddle both lines start to move. Changing the font size or the width of the box is not an option as this is part of a plugin people use with their preferences regarding font appearance. The box is an image and the text is its caption.